# Magento 1.3 .ru bots attack!

Tags: magento-1, security, magento-1.3

I'm being attacked by .ru bots on my Magento 1.3.

Is there any plugin that works for this old version?  Or a way to block them?

[image]

Comment: you have using  too old version,So you should update your magento system to latest version

Comment: I'm working on migrating, and it's gonna take a huge amount of time, since it's a huge project. I need a temporary solution .

Comment: Is it Community version or Enterprise edition?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Community version

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you add the captcha for front end in the admin panel, Sure you will be safe from .ru emails. I have already tested this.
2. Login to admin panel then delete all .ru emails and customers.

**To enable Captcha for front-end**

1. You can enable it by navigating to System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration,
2. Select Yes for field Enables CAPTCHA on Frontend. There are a number of options here for frontend CAPTCHA.

[image]

1. Otherwise, we have the extension called Recaptcha from Magecomp [Magecomp Recaptcha](https://magecomp.com/magento-google-recaptcha.html)

It will be on the following pages :

- Contact Form
- Review Form
- Register Form
- Checkout Page

Comment: I don't hape Captha in that category, I'll attach the image in the issue desciption.

Comment: And Magecomp extension is not compatible with magento 1.3